# In ARM64 assembly code, when is register 31 XZR versus SP?

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, arm64, machine-code, instructions

In ARM64 assembly code, when does register number 31 mean XZR and when does it mean SP?

Comment: It depends on the instruction and each instruction is different with little to no apparent system. Though the instructions are usually cleverly encoded such that any reasonable use of the two registers is possible.

Comment: @fuz Is there notation in the architecture manual saying when register 31 means XZR and when it means SP?

Comment: The ARM Reference manual writes `Xn` when `XZR` can be used and `Xn|SP` when `SP` can be used.  See the introduction to §5 “A64 INSTRUCTION SET.”  Some mnemonics have multiple forms such that both a form with an `Xn` operand and one with an `Xn|SP` operand are available.  The assembler should pick the right one as needed.

Comment: @fuz Thanks!  Is there some way to turn your response into an answer?  If not, just copy and paste as an answer and I'll flag it as good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whether an instruction interprets register 31 as the zero register `wzr`/`xzr` or the stack pointer `wsp`/`xsp` depends on the instruction type and isn't easily predictable.  The same mnemonic may refer to multiple instructions, some of which accept the stack pointer as an operand and others that don't.  In general though, all instructions that make sense to use with the stack pointer have a form where they can be used with the stack pointer.  The assembler automatically picks an appropriate form for you.  It will never silently take `sp` to mean `xzr` or vice versa.

In the ARM Reference Manual, `Xn` or `Wn` is used to refer to a register where register 31 refers to the zero register.  `Xn|SP` or `Wn|WSP` is used to refer to a register where register 31 refers to the stack pointer.  See the introduction to §5 “A64 INSTRUCTION SET” for details.